# How to select all the unique gmail emails from a set of emails?

Tags: mysql, sql, email, gmail

I noticed that gmail doesn't care if the `.` exists in the email or not, which means that `ex.ample@gmail.com` is equivalent to `exam.ple@gmail.com`, which is a nice feature by Google, but a PITA for developers trying to maintain a list of unique email addresses.

I have a table with a list of emails. What are the exact rules gmail uses to detect a unique email, and given a set of emails, how do I find the *actual* unique emails?

Here's my schema:

```
sql> select * from subscribers;

id |     email           
-------------------------
1  | user.name1@gmail.com
2  | username.1@gmail.com
3  | user3@example.net
...
```

The expected output is the set of unique (and valid!) emails:

```
id |     email           
-------------------------
1  | user.name1@gmail.com
3  | user3@example.net
```

[Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b3eb5/1)

Comment: what is the database you use?

Comment: `select distinct replace(email,'.','') from yourtable`

Comment: @Indian Won't it also replace the `.` in `gmail.com`?

Comment: @JohnBupit - Try this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b3eb5/9

Comment: @Indian [Still misses some cases](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a81a4), I think. Consider the email `mailcomsomething@yahoo.com`, which would be converted to `mail.comsomething@yahoo.com` - which is an invalid email.

Comment: @JohnBupit - Hope this will work in all cases http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b3eb5/22

Comment: @Indian I'm afraid not. Fails for non gmail mails.

Comment: @JohnBupit - add a filter then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select em, count(*)
from (
select replace(email, '.','') as em
from subscribers
where email like '%@gmail.com%') t
group by em
having count(*) = 1;
```

Is this what you are trying to do?

Edit: To select distinct emails

```
select distinct 
concat(replace(substring(email,1,INSTR(email,'@')-1),'.',''),    
       substring(email,INSTR(email,'@')))
from subscribers;
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ce70a/2)

Comment: yes..because all the emails are duplicates..If you just need to see the unique emails you don't need the `group by`. will edit my answer.

Comment: This would exclude the non gmail emails. But I guess they could simply be unioned. Also, the `.` from the `gmail.com` is not present in the output.

Comment: @JohnBupit..please see the updated code to only select the distinct emails, disregarding `.` before `@`

Comment: Do not forget the `+` sign which is very powerful and can be used for abuse: https://gmail.googleblog.com/2008/03/2-hidden-ways-to-get-more-from-your.html Also note that hotmail and yahoo have some similare tricks but with different characters.